# How to configure Text to PDF programe as Printer in Server 2012 to be used on server for creating PDF's

Tags: c#, pdf, server, printers

My goal is to have a C# web forms app on **Server 2012 R2** that converts text (and a picture) to PDF and sends it to a client. **I have all of the code, just need to set up the printer correctly.** The printer (PDF programe) has to be accesible via client-side browser (it sends the request, server creates the PDF with printer and sends it to client).

Whatever I try, the result is:

> Unable to determine the application folder of the printer
>   '\server-name\Win2PDF'. Reinstalling the printer using the setup
>   program may fix the problem.

First step is to chose a **free** **Text to PDF** programe that works on **Server 2012 R2** (because **Microsoft Print to PDF** doesn't for some reason). The only place my programe mentions the PDF programe is choosing printer name in code:

```
"PdfSettings.PrinterName = Win2PDF;".
```

Options so far:

- Win2PDF - Best so far. Only adds an extra blank page to the document (acceptable).
- CutePDF - Doesn't support .NET
- bioPDF - Red watermark on the bottom
- PDFsharp - I'd have to implement document-creating logic all over again (a lot of work)
- Spire.PDF - Free trial
- Win10PDF - Free trial, watermark

Second, I go to **Print Managment**, **Print Servers**, **Printers**, then choose the installed programe (Win2PDF), **Properties**:

- **Sharing**: check "**Share this printer**"
- **Ports**: not sure what to select so I **enabled printer spooling** and also checked an **Standard TCP/IP Port** (that i created earlier)
- **Security**: I made sure every user there has permission to Print.

When I right click Win2PDF and go to **List in directory** I get:

> The selected printer cannot be published. The directory service is unavalible.

I'm not sure what to do with **Deploy with Group Policy**.

I also enabled **Branch Office Direct Printing** for the hell of it.

Third, I made sure **Printer Spooler** is running. When I go to /System32/spool/PRINTERS I see an empty folder, is that a problem? Some people suggest trying to delete the contents of the PRINTERS folder, but I can't delete nothing. Also, after I installed the Spooling feature the article said to go to **Server Manager**, **Print Services** and see if **Spooling** is on the list ([like this](https://i-technet.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC585627.jpeg)) and it's not on my list! Is that a problem?

I have no idea what's wrong or what to try next. Please help!

Comment: A PDF library like iText#/PdfSharp would enable you to construct and save/stream a PDF without bothering with a virtual printer at all.

Comment: The problem is implementing the printing logic all over again (a fairly complicated report). If i don't find a solution It seems I'll have to use one of there two. Thanks @Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is trying a different approach. I shouldn't have tried working with the virtual printer (i haven't found a way to make it work).

To create a PDF from code, the best way is using iTextSharp.dll. With that you need a handful of code (not much, but you got to know what you're doing).